# Print Javascript is blank with Display : block/none

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

Someone in this forum help me for Print a div with Javascript.
But when a put Display none for the content that I don't want and display block for the div i want print, my print function show me a blank page.

But if i put Visibility : Hidden/Visible, my print work but i got my result with many white page cause of the Viability only is hidden

I do a code pen : 
[enter link description here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMYMBB)

My CSS : `

```
body * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .print-div, .print-div * {
    display: block !important;
  }`
```

Javascript

```
    function addPrintClassAndPrintDiv(divId) {

   //remove .print-div class from all element if any 
     $(".print-div").removeClass("print-div"); 

   //add .print-div class to that div you want to print
     $("#"+divId).addClass("print-div");

   //print 
      window.print();
}
```

So I want the possibility of print any div and the result is print each div in one page only

Thanks you !

Comment: are you looking for css property `page-break-after`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the easiest solution for you would be to take the visibility hidden/visible approach that you outlined and simply make all elements that do NOT have the `print-div` class `height: 0`. Assuming that all the elements you want to either print or hide (your print-divs) are `<article>` elements you can use the following CSS:

```
body * {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.print-div, .print-div * {
    visibility: visible;
}

article:not(.print-div) {
    height: 0;
}
```

The `:not()` pseudo selector will target all elements that do not have the `print-div` class.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. As a sidenote, I do recommend the cleaner solution of adding a class to the div you want to print, and replacing all three rules with a single one:

`.print-div:not(.printme) { display: none; }`